# How to wait for Firebase storage image upload, then run next function

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, promise, firebase-storage

I'm trying to write a function that uploads several images to Firebase, saves the URLs that get returned to an object, and then uploads that object to my Cloud Firestore. I don't really have a firm understanding of async/await or promises, so if anyone could help, it would be much appreciated.

Basically, I want `uploadImages()` to finish running and then run `uploadData()`, where `saveIssue()` is fired when a form is submitted.

Here's what I'm working with:

```
saveIssue() {
  this.uploadImages();
  this.uploadData();
},
uploadData() {
  let self = this;
  db.collection("issues")
    .add(self.issue)
    .then(docRef => {
      self.$router.push({
        name: "ReportPage",
        params: { issueId: docRef.id }
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
    });
},
uploadImages() {
  const storageRef = storage.ref();
  let self = this;
  this.imagePreviews.forEach(image => {
    let imageName = uuidv1();
    let fileExt = image.fileName.split(".").pop();
    let uploadTask = storageRef
      .child(`images/${imageName}.${fileExt}`)
      .putString(image.base64String, "data_url");
    uploadTask.on("state_changed", {
      error: error => {
        console.error(error);
      },
      complete: () => {
        uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(downloadURL => {
          self.issue.images.push(downloadURL);
        });
      }
    });
  });
},
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to use promises, as explained [here](http://https:%20//developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises). You can rewrite your code to support async wait, since firebase supports it out of the box, but for the beginning it can be like this:

```js
async saveIssue() {
    await this.uploadImages();
    await this.uploadData();
  },
  uploadData() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let self = this;
      db.collection("issues")
        .add(self.issue)
        .then(docRef => {
          self.$router.push({
            name: "ReportPage",
            params: {
              issueId: docRef.id
            }
          });
          resolve();
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error(error);
          reject(error);
        });
    })
  },
  uploadImages() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const storageRef = storage.ref();
      let self = this;
      this.imagePreviews.forEach(image => {
        let imageName = uuidv1();
        let fileExt = image.fileName.split(".").pop();
        let uploadTask = storageRef
          .child(`images/${imageName}.${fileExt}`)
          .putString(image.base64String, "data_url");
        uploadTask.on("state_changed", {
          error: error => {
            console.error(error);
            reject(error);
          },
          complete: () => {
            uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(downloadURL => {
              self.issue.images.push(downloadURL);
              resolve();
            });
          }
        });
      });
    })
  },
```

Comment: Okay, this seems like a good start. It works for the first loop in the for each, but not for the rest. Any insight there?

Comment: You need to look towards Promise.all, read about all async/await stuff here: https://javascript.info/async-await - you basically have to create multiple promises and then run it one by one

Comment: thanks for the answer. is it possible to not create a new promise as described here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/55806234/144088) but still monitor the upload state?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I found a solution based on [@AlexBrohshtut's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60910323/12076283). I still had an issue where the first loop finishing would allow the await to continue, the code below seems to fix that. Happy to update if anyone has a more succinct answer! (I'm intermediate at best...)

```
 saveIssue() {
  Promise.all(
    this.imagePreviews.map(async image => {
      return await this.uploadImages(image);
    })
  ).then(() => {
    this.uploadData();
  });
},
uploadData() {
  let self = this;
  db.collection("issues")
    .add(self.issue)
    .then(docRef => {
      self.$router.push({
        name: "ReportPage",
        params: {
          issueId: docRef.id
        }
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
    });
},
uploadImages(image) {
  const storageRef = storage.ref();
  let self = this;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let imageName = uuidv1();
    let fileExt = image.fileName.split(".").pop();
    let uploadTask = storageRef
      .child(`images/${imageName}.${fileExt}`)
      .putString(image.base64String, "data_url");
    uploadTask.on("state_changed", {
      error: error => {
        console.error(error);
        reject(error);
      },
      complete: () => {
        uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(downloadURL => {
          self.issue.images.push(downloadURL);
          resolve();
        });
      }
    });
  });
}
```