# Function when file upload is complete

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I'm using JavaScript to upload a file to Firebase Storage. I don't know how to do a function when the file upload is complete. I tried to use `.then` but that didn't work.

So until I have another method, I keep checking every 10ms with a `window.setInterval()` if the value of the uploader is 100%

I'm using this script to check until it's done uploading:

```js
task.on("state_changed",
  function progress(snapshot) {
    let percentage = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
    uploader.value = percentage;
    window.setInterval(function () {
      if (uploader.value === 100) {
        // The upload is complete!
        window.alert("Upload complete");
      };
    },10)
  }
);
```

But because I am doing it to fast, I'm getting this error in the Chrome console 276 times:

> [image: Unchecked runtime.lastError: This request exceeds the MAX_WRITE_OPERATIONS_PER_MINUTE quota.]

Is there another way to check when my upload is completed?

(I am using Firebase Storage for my file hosting).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yikes, please don't use a `setInterval` like that. At best it wastes resources and make your laptop fan go all noisy on you, but more commonly it'll upset Chrome (as it does for you), or worse: your users.

To detect when the upload is complete, you need to add additional callback methods to `uploadTask.on('state_changed',`:

```
task.on("state_changed", function(snapshot) {
  let percentage = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
  uploader.value = percentage;
}), function(error) {
  // Handle unsuccessful uploads
}, function() {
  window.alert("Upload complete");
});
```

For more on see the Firebase documentation on [uploading files](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files), specifically the section on [Monitoring upload progress](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#monitor_upload_progress). This page also includes a full example of uploading data and handling all possible outcomes.

Comment: I would add to the very good answer of Frank that you can very well call `then()` on an `UploadTask`, as explained here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.UploadTask#then: "This object behaves like a Promise, and resolves with its snapshot data when the upload completes". See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55806234/3371862) for an example.

Comment: Good point Renaud. You might want to post an additional answer, so that you can show an example (in context of OPs code).

Answer (score 1):

Note that, in addition to using the [`on()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.UploadTask#on) method to monitor a file upload, an [`UploadTask`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.UploadTask) offers a [`then()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.UploadTask#then) method which returns a Promise that "resolves with its snapshot data when the upload completes".

So, you could use `then()` as follows:

```
    // --- 1. Define your UploadTask
    // You don't show how you do that in your question but it is something like the following, using the put() method

    const file = ....;
    const metadata = {
      contentType: "...."
    };

    const fileRef = storageRef.child(...);
    const uploadTask = fileRef.put(file, metadata); 

    // --- 2. Call the then() method on this UploadTask
    uploadTask
    .then(uploadTaskSnapshot => {
           // The upload is complete!
           window.alert("Upload complete");

          //In addition, if needed you can get a Download URL, as follows
          return uploadTaskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
    })
    .then(url  => {
          //Do something with this url...
    })
    .catch(err => {...});
```

Comment: Thanks for adding additional information to the answer that I marked as the solution!